# SQL Rules depend on selected value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following simple DB:

```
Table Types:
- ID int
- TypeName nvarchar

Table Users:
- ID int
- UserName nvarchar
- TypeID int

Table BusyTime
- ID int
- UserID int
- BTime time(0)
```

But one restriction - records in BusyTime should be only for users, which have TypeID = 3. Users with TypeID = 1 and with TypeID = 2 can't have records in BusyTime (it contradicts the business logic)
How to describe it on MS SQL level? Or should I redesign DB ?

Comment: Triggers can be used to ensure data consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your primary keys in each table are just on `ID`. What you need to change is, add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on *both* `ID` and `TypeID` in `Users`:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_User_Types_XRef (ID,TypeID)
```

And create the `BusyTime` table as:

```
CREATE TABLE BusyTime (
   ID int not null,
   UserID int not null,
   BTime time(0) not null,
   _Type_XRef as 3 persisted,
   constraint PK_BusyTime PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   constraint FK_BusyTime_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
        references Users (ID),
   constraint FK_BusyTime_Users_XRef FOREIGN KEY (UserID,_Type_XRef) 
        references Users (ID,TypeID)
)
```

Where I've assumed `PK_BusyTime` and `FK_BusyTime_Users` were your existing constraints. It's a matter of taste whether you drop `FK_BusyTime_Users` (which is the "real" foreign key constraint) now that `FK_BusyTime_Users_XRef` exists.

Comment: Nice, and then you create a view to be used on a daily basis, hiding that dummy columns needed to make fk possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use check constraints to disallow invalid types:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, you basically define a function which could query different tables. You can use the MSDN example

Comment: But you'd still need to implement a trigger on the `Users` table to prevent `TypeID` from being changed from 3 to something else, *if* that user has any rows in `BusyTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up such a conditional constraint is possible.  One method is to add compound index to `users`:

```
create unique index idx_users(type, id) on users(type, id)
```

Then use this for a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table busytime add _type as (3) persisted not null;
alter table busytime add constraint foreign key (_type, userId) on users(type, id);
```

Unfortunately, I think the `persisted` is needed for this column so it actually occupies space in the record.

Unfortunately, I don't think this works either:

```
alter table busytime add constraint foreign key (3, userId) on users(type, id);
```